How to get files on root folder drive PHP MS Graph SDK
It can be easy question but the documentation is not clear or has a bug.
When you want to get files from known folder, this is the way:
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children
<?php
use Microsoft\Graph\GraphServiceClient;
$graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);
$result = $graphServiceClient->drives()->byDriveId('drive-id')->items()->byDriveItemId('driveItem-id')->children()->get()->wait();


you have a DriveId and DriveItemdId, and then you ask files...
But if you want the files from root folder of drive, the url is the following:
GET /me/drive/root/children
But, Could you tell me how it is with PHP SDK? Because the documentation show the other, how if you known the folder Id.
This is url of documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php
Thank you

Isn't that exactly what the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php#list-children-in-the-root-of-the-current-users-drive is talking about? Says there, "To retrieve files in the root of the drive, use the root relationship on the drive, then access the children relationship."

I'm afraid that in this case you need to call the Graph API twice.
Once to get yours drive's id and then to get children inside the root of the drive.
$graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);

$drive = $graphServiceClient->me()->drive()->get()->wait();

$result = $graphServiceClient->drives()->byDriveId($drive->getId())->items()->byDriveItemId('root')->children()->get()->wait();

I think that the SDK doesn't generate a client code like
$result = $graphServiceClient->me()->drive()->items()->byDriveItemId('root')->children()->get()->wait();

